# Implementing a SMTP server on a personal computer (windows)

Tags: windows, smtp

I need a very simple SMTP server running on my computer for notification software that I developed. I tried "Free SMTP SERVER" and "QK SMTP SERVER 3", but for some reason they don't work, they always give me a time out error.

Do you know some good SMTP server software? Thanks.

Comment: There are many, many reasons this could be failing.  Are you having trouble injecting mail into the queue, or getting deliveries from the queue?  You may want to move this question to serverfault.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why go through all the trouble? Sign up for a gmail account and use their SMTP server.

http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server

It's likely that even if you setup a local smtp server you won't be able to send mail to any outside email servers. (only local delivery). Outside servers will probably reject your smtp server since you're likely in a block of IPs known to be dynamic i.e. not static / business class. This is a spam prevention mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to say this, but have you tried using the mailserver that comes with IIS?

Comment: No, i dont want a big app like this, i only need a simple SMTP server

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just install the SMTP server part of IIS.

Comment: smtp server that comes with IIS isn't a big app.  All it does is send mail via SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

[hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/) is free, and works really well:

> hMailServer is a free e-mail server for Microsoft Windows. It's used
>   by Internet service providers, companies, governments, schools and
>   enthusiasts in all parts of the world.
>
> It supports the common e-mail protocols (IMAP, SMTP and POP3) and can
>   easily be integrated with many existing web mail systems. It has
>   flexible score-based spam protection and can attach to your virus
>   scanner to scan all incoming and outgoing email.

[image]