# Multiple servers on one hardware?

Tags: email, webserver, smtp

I have built a website and have a domain. I want to host the site on my home server. I would like to set up email like an smtp server. Can I host my site and the smtp on the same hardware? If so, what do I need to do to make this work? From my understanding a web server and smtp server use different ports so it should be possible right?

Comment: yes you can, though I don't recommend hosting too many services on one box, just due to build and maintenance complexity. If the box is beefy, I recommend installing a bare-metal hypervisor like VMWare ESXI, so you can host multiple server OSes on the box, and set up your own little network of servers that are specific for their task. good luck.

Comment: If you don't expect a huge traffic and have capacity + security concerns in control, no problem in doing that.

Comment: Your ISP may not like (allow) running your own SMTP server - if not correctly configured it can be used to send spam ... see this answer [Anyway to create SMTP Server on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/a/354372) for more info.

Comment: I expect very low traffic. It's a resume like website. Just thought it'd be cool to have my own email address also like @myname.com. the email and website would only be used for showing off skills and possibly streaming my own media from one machine to another.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why this shouldn't work, I've been doing something like that for many years.

One thing to keep in mind is that doing this really only makes sense if you have a fixed IP address, *and* your provider allows incoming SMTP traffic. At least in the Netherlands more providers are allowing this, realizing that potential trouble starts when allowing *outgoing* SMTP; so you may have to configure the mail server to send out email via the provider's smarthost if you want to be able to reply to messages sent to your own domain.